# How to tell if the navbar is collapsed in order to toggle items in the navbar list

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to:

- display an image - if the menu is extended
- display text - if the menu is collapsed (when the "3 lines button" appears)

Here is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-idebaca navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" 
                data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/iebaca.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <img ng-show="somethingt to catch if the menu is collapsed"
                     src="img/button-aree.png">
                <a id="areelink" href="#" 
                   ng-hide="somethingt to catch if the menu is collapsed" 
                   ng-click="sendmessage('')">Aree</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: `display an image if the menu is "extended "` -- do you mean when the menu is open and the menu nav is visible?  Or are you trying to get different behavior on different screen sizes?

Comment: i'm trying to get different behavior on different screen sizes!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want bootstrap's [responsive utility classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities).

The `hidden-sm` class will hide an element on small screens.

The `visible-sm-block`, `visible-sm-inline`, `visible-sm-inline-block` classes will show an element *only* on small screens.

Comment: i tried :   <li ><img  class="hidden-xs" src="img/button-aree.png"><a   class="visible-xs-block"   id="areelink" href="#" ng-click="sendmessage('')" >Aree</a></li>     but it  doesn't work!

Comment: works only this way : <li ><img  class="visible-lg-block hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md " src="img/button-aree.png"><a   class="hidden-lg"   id="areelink" href="#" ng-click="sendmessage('')" >Aree</a></li>

Comment: So you only want the menu to show on lg, and the button to show on md, sm and xs?

Comment: i would display the image if the menu is not in the "mobile mode" , when appears the menu button and all collapse i want to display a text and hide the image,but your advice is very useful!!!thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has it all contained within the standard CSS to do it all, if you look at this: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default it has a pretty good demo of how to do it, i'd suggest starting with this, and then modifying it to display the content you want.

navbar-toggle kicks in when the screen size goes over 768 pixels:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-toggle {
  display: none;
}
```

you can then use collapse and navbar-collapse to control the expanded mode for larger displays.:

```
.collapse {
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
  display: block!important;
  height: auto!important;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  overflow: visible!important;
}
```